# Xcode - Run code each day on 00:00

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer, synchronization

I need a piece of code for Xcode *(obj-c)* that runs every day at 00:00.
The reason for this is because my server updates data each new day and I would like my app to synchronize with the update.

I was thinking about doing a timer that runs every minute and checks the time (from internet, **not** the phones time), but it seems like there could be an more efficient way.

*Help or pointers really appreciated!

Thanks*

Comment: There is no way of ensuring your app will be in memory at 00:00 every day. In fact, I would say that it is more likely to NOT be in memory.

Comment: If the user restarts the app after 00:00 right now, he will get the new information from the server. The problem is that if the app remains open after 00:00 it doesn't get synchronized with the new data and that's when I want it to be synced. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 0):

Use the calendar app on your mac.  Set up a recurring event every day at 0:00.  At the point where you pick the type of alert, you can select an option to open a file (as opposed to a pop-up, etc.).  Pick your app as the file to be opened.

Comment: Although it's not made particularly clear in the question, the OP reference "the phones times" and tagged the question "ios". I think it's fair to assume that the question is about running code **on iOS** at 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

When the app becomes active, register a local notification (UILocalNotification) to trigger at midnight.

Then, you can perform the updates at the app delegate's `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

You can then cancel the notification when the application goes to background by calling the UIApplication's method `-cancelLocalNotification:`

Comment: Of course that you also have to update when the app is opened, my answer only covers triggering the update if the user has the app opened at midnight.
The @Subhransu answer says that notifications are not guaranteed, but that only applies to remote notifications. Apple doesn't state that local notifications are not guaranteed. Besides, his answer doesn't solve the update at midnight when the user is using the app.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's even required to use notification here. Notification is usually on best effort basis and doesn't guarantee the delivery. This can be done in few simple steps.

1. Save the lastUpdated time in your iOS app. Probably in NSUserDefaults or if you're using local database you can store it there as well.
2. Everytime user launches the application check how much time has elapsed since last update.
3. If it's more than 24 hours then make an API call to your server and check if there's any new updates available (which you can determine probably from server timestamp). Get the latest data (possibly only the delta difference in stead of everything).
4. Update the lastUpdated time in your iOS app.

Comment: The notifications that are not guaranteed delivery are the remote notifications, not local notifications. Besides, your answer does not solve the problem, that is updating data at midnight while the user is with the app opened.

Comment: if app is on foreground mode then local notification is the best approach. to fire it on specific time use [scheduleLocalNotification:](http://goo.gl/maZm5l)

Comment: That's exactly my answer.